# Different result when build delphi project from command prompt and Delphi 10 Editor

Tags: dll, exe, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have problem with following code which is written in delphi-10. It excuted properly when it is build from Embarcadero Delphi 10 Editor but when i build module using Command Prompt it gives different result.

Command Prompt build result:
result of Screen.FormCount is zero but there are forms on second monitor

Delphi 10 Build Result:
result of Screen.FormCount is 1 and there is form on second monitor.(which is valid)

might be it is considering only first monitor when running from command prompt.

```
Monitor:=   screen.Forms[Screen.FormCount].Monitor;
        Self.Left := Monitor.Left + ((Monitor.Width - Self.Width) div 2);
        Self.Top :=  Monitor.Top + ((Monitor.Height - Self.Height) div 2);

        ShowMessage((screen.FormCount).ToString());
```

what should i do to work build with command prompt.

Hi @RemyLebeau i debug it again i found that when i build through IDE form count is 2 there are two form open one is from1 and second is MDIchildform but when i build through command prompt it gives form count 1 and only form1. may you please tell why MDIChildform is not consider in command prompt build,eve those both form are in same dll

```
  if(screen.Forms[0].Name <>'') then
    showmessage(screen.Forms[0].Name);
    if(screen.FormCount >0) then
      showmessage(screen.Forms[0].Name);
    if(screen.FormCount >1) then
    showmessage(screen.Forms[1].Name);
```

Comment: `Screen.FormCount` returns the number of instantiated `TForm` objects in memory.  If `FormCount` is 0, there are no `TForm` objects created. That has nothing to do with monitors or commandline vs IDE compilation.

Comment: but it returns 1 when build from delphi 10 editor. same code same scenario @RemyLebeau to identify difference i put message box in both dll compile from IDE and dll compiled from comand line. messagebox shows formcount. dll fromIDE returns 1 as form count and dll compiled from comandline returns 0 for same scenario

Comment: you didn't say it was a DLL project. That does make a difference. The DLL has to share the same RTL instance in memory as the EXE in order to see `TForm` objects created in the EXE. That means compiling the DLL and EXE with Runtime Packages enabled. So the IDE compilation most likely has Runtime Packages enabled, but the command-line compilation does not, causing the DLL to have its own separate copy of the RTL in memory.

Comment: ok. So now what is the solution for this. what should i do, may you suggest? @RemyLebeau

Comment: double check your build settings in each scenario, they are clearly different

Comment: My main form style is set to fsMDIForm FormStyle :=  fsMDIForm; but is is not count with screen.formcount . how to make it countable

Comment: See my comment on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928832/) about that issue.